# ANTLR in Javascript : impossible to parse again a part of code

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I've tried to develop an UI in JavaScript to parse specific code described in my ANTLR4 grammar. I use a visitor to parse all parts of code and generate a questionnaire. Afterwards, depending on users' input in a JavaScript form, I parse the last part of my code to generate results (it's close to the calculator mechanism drafted into ANTLR book). So far so good. Nonetheless, I would like to modify inputs in the JavaScript form and parse a second time to regenerate and recalculate some results. At this moment, the AST tree becomes empty. I've tried to reinitialise the lexer the parser, the visitor as such as to create a new instance of the parser. It seems that previous parser and lexer are still active and it is impossible to "move the cursor up" to parse again a specific block of my source code.
Thanks for your precious help.
Chris

Below summarised file and script.
grammar.G4

```
pre
    :   title ('\n')+
        author ('\n')+
    ;               

peri
    :   (statement ('\n')+)*
        (answer ('\n')+)*
    ;   

post
    :   (feedback ('\n')+)* 
    ;

exercise
        :   pre peri post
        ;
//End of Grammar
```

javascript main class :

```
class MyExercise {

constructor(){
    this.chars = antlr4.CharStreams.fromBuffer(input,'utf-8');
    this.lexer = new MyLexer(this.chars);
    this.tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(this.lexer);
    this.parser = new MyParser(this.tokens);
    this.visitor = new LabeledVisitor(this.exercise,this.parser);
    this.parser.buildParseTrees = true;
    tree = this.parser.pre();
    this.visitor.visitPre(tree);
    tree = this.parser.peri();
    this.visitor.visitPeri(tree); 
    this.generateAnswersHTML() // generate HTML results and also inputfields to collect values from user.
    this.generateSubmitButton(); // generate submit HTML button
}

generateSubmitButton(){
    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.setAttribute('type','submit');
    button.setAttribute('value','Check answer');
    button.addEventListener("click",this.checkAnswers.bind(this)); 
    document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(button);
}

checkAnswers(object){
   var tree = this.parser.post();
   this.visitor.visitPost(tree);
  this.generateFeeback(); //Generate HTML feedbacks (function of inputed values by user)
}
}
```

It works well the first time but when I click again on the button checkanswer which calls checkAnswer() method, the tree becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to reparse your input:

1. Recreate your input stream, token source + parser every time.
2. Reset your input stream and token source, by

   - Recreate your input stream or load the new text into your existing one.
   - Call parser.reset().
   - Set your input stream again in the token source (to reset it, just calling .reset() won't cut it). `lexer.setInputStream(input);`
   - Set your token source in the token stream again, for the same reason. `tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);`

Comment: Just to complete my issue, in fact, my input doesn't change at all, so my purpose is to revisit the same tree by taking into account new parameters inputed by user in the UI. In any event, if I test your recommandation it should also work. But First, the method lexer.setInputStream seems to not exist in Javascript. Only lexer.reset() is accepted. Thus, I tried to implement this block : chars = antlr4.CharStreams.fromBuffer(this.input,'utf-8'); parser.reset();lexer.reset();tokens.setTokenSource(this.lexer);var tree = this.parser.post(); this.visitor.visitPost(tree); But the tree is still empty.

Comment: I found another solution, I store my tree in a treebackup before parsing it the first time. Then, the second time I just call visit(treeBackup) and it works in my case. Nevertheless, don't reach to parse again a part of my code is still problematic...